# Windows Phone State Maintenance Issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone, win-universal-app, taskmanager

I have an app developed in Cordova Visual Studio Javascript for Windows Universal.

App was deployed into Nokia Lumia 535 with Windows OS.

When I run Facebook app, Press & Hold Device Backbutton, I can see the Facebook app in Windows app Log.

But My app is not visible there.

This derives to the conclusion that some thing wrong somewhere.

As far as app is concerned, its session variables and app state is being maintained perfectly.

Earlier, the same app was working fine. I have not made any changes to the application with respect to its environment settings such as plugins or code that effects application state.

I am unable to figure out if this is problem with device or device OS or it is problem with application.

Due to this, Camera and gallery plugin operation inside my app is not working.

Looking for some hint that may give me some lead to figure out the reason.

Comment: So, your app isn't being displayed in the Windows Phone app switcher?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. any clue would helpful!!

Comment: I was able to debug in Android and saw code is working fine, plugin is working fine but after the execution, inside cordova 3.6.4, something was happening that is abending the app.I posted another relevant question. I will update there the rest